# Issue while loading css

Tags: html, css

I am getting 404 error while loading css in webapp.
My html content is like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"> -->
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>PSL Inter App</title>
    <meta name="description" content="PSL Inter app for accounting"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1000, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Loading Bootstrap -->
    <link href="WEB-INF/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
    <!-- Loading Flat UI -->
    <link href="WEB-INF/css/flat-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
    <link href="WEB-INF/css/assets/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>

    <!-- <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico"> -->
</head>
<body>
<div class="col-xs-3">
Please Login!!
    <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" value="" placeholder="Username" class="form-control">
    </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

My directory structure is like below:

[image]

Can anyone help here?

Thanks!!

Comment: Where the root of your app?

Comment: Try removing `WEB-INF/ and use like `<link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>`

Comment: tried that also... not working.. :(

Comment: Is this code belonging to the index.html file?

Comment: yes.. it belongs to index.html

Answer (score 1):

You need to find what folder is the root of your app. 
I think `<link href="/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>` this can help you.

Comment: What server you're using?

Comment: it's tomcat version 7

Answer (score 0):

your css path should be

```
 <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
<!-- Loading Flat UI -->
<link href="css/flat-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
<link href="css/assets/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
```

Comment: I did this in first attempt itself... but its not working... :(

Answer (score 0):

I moved css folder from WEB-INF to WebContent and included it like below and it WORKED!!

```
<link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
<!-- Loading Flat UI -->
<link href="css/flat-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
<link href="css/assets/demo.css" rel="stylesheet" type='text/css'>
```